# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(t+\frac{1}{t})} dt}{t}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can the closed form of the following integral be evaluated?

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(t+\frac{1}{t})} dt}{t}$$

I could not find any substitution nor factorisation that can be applied here.

I am not getting any idea regarding the evaluation of this integral. I referred a similiar question posted here, yet I could not relate it with this definite integral.

What should be done to find the above definite integral?

Comment: it should be $$2\,{{ K}_{0}\left(2\right)}$$

Comment: ... Thank you Mathematica...

Comment: $2k_0(x)$ is the modified  Bessel function of the second Kind, it was not Mathematica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To elaborate on the answer in the comments, substitute $t = e^u$, giving
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-(t+\frac 1t)}}{t} dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty  e^{-(e^u + e^{-u})} du \\ = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-2\cosh u} du \\ = 2K_0(2)$$

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, which function is $K_i(x)$ ?

Comment: $K_n(x)$ refers to the [modified Bessel functions of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).